# horizontally aligning multiple divs (CSS)

Tags: html, css, alignment

I need to align these `div`s so that the space between "content1" and the red `div` equals the space between "content4" and the red `div`. **I don't mind changing the blue-`div`'s margin but this should work for any width.**

I used to achieve this by making the *width of the 4 blue `div`s + their left and right margins = 100%* but that doesn't seem to work well in this case.

I also tried adding another `div` inside the red one that contained all the blue `div`s and giving it `margin: 0 auto` but that's not working either.

[**Code in jsfiddle (updated)**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranLegon/L7qpgdkk/7/)

PS: if i'm not clear enough, please feel free to edit my question.

Comment: What are we allowed to adjust? Are the width or margins adjustable? Do you have an image of what the expect result shoudl be?

Comment: @Paulie_D you can adjust  blue-div's margins but not the width. They will have an image but i can handle that later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the incredible property box-sizing: border-box; supported by all modern browser, IE8 included!
And set the width and margin on % :

```
.red, .blue {
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:        border-box;
}

.red {
    width:650px;
    height:1000px;
    background:red;
    padding: 1% 0 0 1%; // Space top and left of red
}

.blue {
    height:200px;
    width: 24%;
    background:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0; // Space bottom and right of each blue
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/L7qpgdkk/3/

Comment: thank you! but what is the `overflow: hidden` for?

Comment: yeah! we dont need it in this case i gonna edit

Comment: As an extension of the above, I tried to center the text "Content1", "Content2" in their respective blue boxes, but it didn't work.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, its quite easy. Check this out

HTML

```
<div class="red">
    <div class="blue"><div>content1</div></div>
    <div class="blue"><div>content2</div></div>
    <div class="blue"><div>content3</div></div>
    <div class="blue"><div>content4</div></div>
    <div class="blue"><div>content5</div></div>
    <div class="blue"><div>content6</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.red {
    width:680px;
    height:1000px;
    background:red;
}

.blue {
    width: 25%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1%;
}

.blue > div {
    background:blue;
    height:200px;
}
```

[Fiddle this](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qpgdkk/2/).

Comment: but the result must work even if the blue-div's width isn't 20% or 25%

Comment: in this case,

blue-div: width = 100% / (Numbers of blue-div) .

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is wrong: (20% * 4) + (1% * 4) = 88%.

You have to set top / left margin to 4% so width will be: 80% + (5 * 4%) = 100%.

Added also `font-size: 0` to correct `inline-block` problem with white spacing.

```
.blue {
    margin: 4% 0 0 4%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7qpgdkk/1/

Reference: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: still shows some less margin on right

Comment: Working just fine in my side.

Comment: I dont know why it shows more on right, on my side.. but i agree this is a nice solution

Comment: @emmanuel i know the sum doesn't equal 100%, thats why i said i **used to** do it that way. The `font-size:0` will be useful though